# Hi, Is it possible to backup my app data?

Tags: flutter, backup

Objective: backing up my Notekeeping app data such that I can sync it back if I lost my data.

May I know how am I able to do it? I have tried searching for answers online, but unfortunately I am unable to find a clear approach to it.

I have seen some apps that uses googldrive, or zip file approach. May I know what is the best approach? And also how am I able to do it. Thanks! All help is deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes , its possible to upload your users data to their respective google drive account and retrive back when again user installed your app.

You can follow this link to know more
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/google-drive-integration-in-flutter-upload-download-list-files